# Get sum of fiscal year and group SQL results accordingly

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following code to create the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE PaL (
    country TEXT,
    Day DATE,
    Revenue CHAR(255),
    Costs CHAR(255)
);


INSERT INTO PaL 
(country, Day, Revenue, Costs)
VALUES

("DE", "2017-01-31", "5600", "-3000"),
("DE", "2017-02-28", "3900", "-1550"), 
("DE", "2017-03-31", "4100", "-2200"),
("DE", "2017-04-30", "7200", "-5000"),
("DE", "2017-05-31", "5300", "-4000"),
("DE", "2017-06-30", "8800", "-6550"), 
("DE", "2017-07-31", "1120", "-500"),
("DE", "2017-08-31", "5000", "-3250"),
("DE", "2017-09-30", "2600", "-1225"),
("DE", "2017-10-31", "9200", "-8350"), 
("DE", "2017-11-30", "5100", "-2995"),
("DE", "2017-12-31", "3950", "-3400"),

("DE", "2018-01-31", "7840", "-6985"),
("DE", "2018-02-28", "9358", "-1452"), 
("DE", "2018-03-31", "2225", "-1655"),
("DE", "2018-04-30", "3820", "-2950"),
("DE", "2018-05-31", "9587", "-8500"),
("DE", "2018-06-30", "3000", "-2785"), 
("DE", "2018-07-31", "5450", "-4500"),
("DE", "2018-08-31", "3800", "-2650"),
("DE", "2018-09-30", "9000", "-7456"),
("DE", "2018-10-31", "7780", "-6900"), 
("DE", "2018-11-30", "6585", "-5450"),
("DE", "2018-12-31", "1280", "-850"),

("DE", "2019-01-31", "6585", "-5450"),
("DE", "2019-02-28", "1280", "-850");
```

Then I use the following code to query the revenue from it:

```
Select country, sum(Revenue)
From Pal
Where Day Between '2017-03-01' AND '2017-02-28'
Group By country
```

You can also find everything in the SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d8da8/1)
All this works fine so far.

---

However, my target is that the SQL result in the end looks like this:

```
 Fiscal Year      Country                    Values
    2017            DE          Sum from 2017-03-01 - 2018-02-28
    2018            DE          Sum from 2018-03-01 - 2019-02-28
```

What do I have to change in my code to get the desired result?

Comment: Why on earth do you store the numbers as `char(255)`? What's wrong with `integer`? Assuming 2 letter ISO codes, `country` maybe should be a `varchar(2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the fiscal year by subtracting 2 months and extracting the year.  So:

```
Select year(day - interval 2 month) as fy,
      country, sum(Revenue)
From Pal
Group By fy, country
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, works perfectly :-) Do you also have an idea how I can include the ROLLUP WITH function so the sum of the column is only shown once and not for each year. See SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d8da8/10

Comment: Notice that the fiscal year is defined by its end date not start date so if you do `year(day - interval 2 month) + 1 as fy` it will be more correct

Comment: @Joakim Danielson: Good point but I think it depends on how it is defined in your company. If the fiscal year 2017 is assigned to the calender year 01.03.2017 - 28.02.2018 the solution from Gordon is the correct way. If the fiscal year 2018 is assigned to the calender year 01.03.2017 - 28.02.2018 then your solution is the right choice.

Comment: I have added both ways to the SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d8da8/14

Comment: @JoakimDanielson . . . Actually not.  The fiscal year 2017 is defined as "Sum from 2017-03-01 - 2018-02-28".  In any case, the `+ 1` doesn't really change the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I mean that the fiscal year  2017-03-01 - 2018-02-28 should be labeled as "2018", the sum should be calculated as you have done in your query

Comment: @JoakimDanielson . . . Not to push the point, but the last table in the question explicitly says that "2017" refers to "2017-03-01 - 2018-02-28".  I can see why others might call that fiscal yer 2018, but the OP does not.